# count the same data of words with data in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have sentence, I wanna split into words, and then check them with the data in stopword table. I wanna count the number of same data (total). but, total doesn't give me the total of same data. How to sum the data I need ? thanks

```
$word ='temporal. the text mining in a evolutionary a theme patterns  theme threads  clustering'; 
$symbol    = array(".", ",", "\\", "-", "\"", "(", ")", "<", ">", "?", ";", ":", "+", "%", "\r", "\t", "\0", "\x0B");
$cleanMeta = str_replace($symbol, " ", $word);
$key     = strtolower($cleanMeta);
$key = explode(" ", trim($key));

foreach($key as $word_key){
    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(stoplist_word) AS total FROM tb_stopword  WHERE stoplist_word = '$word_key'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $row1 = $row['total'];
        echo $row1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what your get if `var_dump ($key) before foreach` ?

Comment: @GBD `array(14) { [0]=> string(8) "temporal" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(4) "text" [3]=> string(6) "mining" [4]=> string(2) "in" [5]=> string(12) "evolutionary" [6]=> string(1) "a" [7]=> string(5) "theme" [8]=> string(8) "patterns" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(5) "theme" [11]=> string(7) "threads" [12]=> string(0) "" [13]=> string(10) "clustering" }`

Comment: you are not getting `total` for each keyword?

Comment: @GBD i got the total of each word, I wanna get the total of all words

Comment: see answer of @Hugo Delsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering you already cleaned the input string, you dont need a foreach with a new query for every word. You could do:

```
$word ='temporal. the text mining in a evolutionary a theme patterns  theme threads  clustering'; 
$symbol    = array(".", ",", "\\", "-", "\"", "(", ")", "<", ">", "?", ";", ":", "+", "%", "\r", "\t", "\0", "\x0B");
$cleanMeta = str_replace($symbol, " ", $word);
$key       = trim(strtolower($cleanMeta));
$key       = str_replace("'","''",$key);
$keys      = "'".str_replace(" ","', '", $key)."'";

$query  = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(stoplist_word) AS total FROM tb_stopword  WHERE   stoplist_word IN ($keys)");
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$total = $row['total'];

echo $total;
```

if you realy want the foreach use:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($key as $word_key){
    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(stoplist_word) AS total FROM tb_stopword  WHERE stoplist_word = '$word_key'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $total += $row['total'];
    }
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: You may want to use `mysqli` or `PDO` and prepared statement, variable binding to avoid parsing the same SQL over and over again in the `foreach` solution.

Comment: I just used his own code to make it understandable for him to use. Changing to mysqli, although highly advised, would mostlikely mean he must update all his pages.